# Show by definition of limit that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}e^x = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My proof:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}e^x = 1$$
We have :
$$|e^x-1|<\epsilon$$
And:
$$|x-0|<\delta$$

$$|x|<\delta $$

Then we do $x>0$ and remove the absolute signs:

$$e^x-1<\epsilon$$
$$x<\ln{(\epsilon +1)}$$

So $$\ln{(\epsilon +1)} = \delta $$

End of proof. Is it correct? Is there a better way?

Comment: If you'd want to make it simpler, just use the series expansion of $e^x$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan, you have that backwards. Given any $\varepsilon > 0,$ one must exhibit a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon|$ for all $|x - a| < \delta.$ For our case, we have that $f(x) = e^x,$ $L = 1,$ and $a = 0.$

Comment: Oh sorry, that's right @Carlo

Comment: By the way, you have only proved that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^x = 1.$ One must also check that $\lim_{x \to 0^-} e^x = 1.$ But you can do a similar argument to find that $\delta = -\ln(1 - \varepsilon)$ will do the trick in that case.

Comment: @Carlo How do I prove it from the other side?

Comment: @BiliDebili, given any $\varepsilon > 0,$ choose $\delta = -\ln(1 - \varepsilon).$ Convince yourself first that we have $\delta > 0;$ then prove that for any $|x| < \delta,$ we have that $|e^x - 1| < \varepsilon.$ Use the fact that $x < 0.$